# Compiling error with g++ 4.9 on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, g++, osx-yosemite-beta

Recently I installed the new version of gcc (4.9) on OSX Yosemite, following the steps that I found on:

https://wiki.helsinki.fi/display/HUGG/Installing+the+GNU+compilers+on+Mac+OS+X

But when I try to compile a simple "Hello World" program, the compiler print the next:

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated.
```

It seems to be a easy problem to solve, but I'm new using this OS. So I don't want to mess it up.

Thank you!.

---

The code is just a "Hello World" :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

Then I complile with `g++` on Terminal like this: `g++ hw.cpp -o hw.o`

The the result is: `fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory`

Comment: are you using `g++` to compile, or are you using `gcc` by mistake?

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using,

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `gcc` instead of `g++`, try doing the following:

`g++ your_source_file.cpp -std=c++11`

Comment: Missing options: `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: why should these options be missing? If OP just wants to compile, why should he care for debug symbols, and build warnings?

Comment: Because OP is probably a newbie (he won't ask otherwise), and getting all warnings & debug symbols is very useful.